# Find frame in video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an image saved as 1.jpg and I want to find frames similar to this image in a video and get frame numbers of these frames or timestamps.
This command can find similar images but it outputs results in a hard-to-parse format. How can I fix this command to just get the similar frames and no other information?

```
ffmpeg.exe  -i "1.mkv" -r 1 -loop 1 -i 1.jpg -an -filter_complex "blend=difference:shortest=1,blackframe=99:32" -f null -
```

Comment: What's wrong with this method? blackframe doesn't have selective logging. Use some grep/awk..etc to isolate the `frame:` field.

Comment: @Gyan I hoped it does have selective logging or something similar. It would make things simpler a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Use `grep` and `sed`: `-f null - 2>&1 | grep blackframe | sed 's/.*frame\:\(.*\)/\1/'`

full code:

```
ffmpeg.exe  -i "1.mkv" -r 1 -loop 1 -i 1.jpg -an -filter_complex "blend=difference:shortest=1,blackframe=99:32" -f null - 2>&1 | grep blackframe | sed 's/.*frame\:\(.*\)/\1/'
```

`grep blackframe` gives you these lines:

```
[Parsed_blackframe_9 @ 0x7fea7de01b80] frame:199 pblack:99 pts:716400 t:7.960000 type:P last_keyframe:198
```

modify this line with `sed`:

The `s` command (as in substitute) is probably the most important in sed and has a lot of different options. The syntax of the `s` command is`'s/regexp/replacement/flags'`.

in this case the `regexp` (Regex Pattern) is `.*frame\:\(.*\)`

This means `{any characters}frame: {any characters}`

(the `\` are necessary escape characters in Regex for the colon `:` and parentheses `(` `)`.)

The `replacement` is `\1`.

It refers to the characters captured by the escaped parentheses.